# jquery fadeOut callback functions not working

Tags: jquery

I found it in Jquery documentation that `fadeOut()` accepts callback function but in my case that function is not executing?? Take a look:

```
$("div.icon").stop(0,0).fadeOut(250,function(){
    $("div.expanded").stop(0,0).fadeIn(250);    
});

$("div.expanded").stop(0,0).fadeOut(250,function(){
    $("div.icon").stop(0,0).fadeIn(250);
});
```

Do you guys see something that I am missing here??

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the `stop()`, you dont need that. It only stop the animation prematurely.

Comment: He could need it. If something else was animating the .icon or .expanded the .stop() would stop those animations before starting the new ones.

Comment: Yes, that solves it. I guess I have to read that `stop()` page once again. Thanks man!!

Comment: @altschuler: You are right. I've put it there to prevent partial animations from happening. There must be a way around. Will have to look inside that 'stop()' page.

Comment: Did you see my fiddle? .stop() is not the issue :-)

Comment: @daniel.tosaba, setup a demo, I will take a look, if you still have problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jx8hn/

Did you by any chance set opacity:0 on .expanded? Because then it wont fadeIn. In the fiddle i set display:none which seems to work.

Comment: I haven't, it's set `display:none` as you did.

Comment: Thats really odd then. Are you sure the callback is not triggered? You can test it with an alert("test") and/or console.log("test") and see if that happens.

Comment: Alert pops up but animation doesn't occur. You might wanna check http://danieltosaba.webuda.com/wordpress. Now it is set to work without stop. It is weird indeed :)

Comment: Hmm. Last guess; try using .stop(true, true) instead of .stop(0,0). It will then clear the animation queue and jump to the end of animation, and then start the new animation.

Comment: Yeah!! That is better way to do it. Why do you think this happens??

Comment: Actually, it's still messed up. Will have to play with that one. But thanks again for your effort!!!